# Why parameter's address is same? When in different function inside

Tags: c, pointers

I am confused, When I pass different pointer into different functions, but the parameter's address of value in the function is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//char arr[]={'c', 'a', 't'};

void print(char ca[])
{
    printf("&ca=%p, &ca[0]=%p, &ca[1]=%p, ", &ca, &ca[0], &ca[1]);
    printf("++ca=%p\n",++ca);
    printf("*ca=%c\n",*ca);
}

void print2(const char *pa)
{
    printf("&pa=%p, &(pa[0])=%p, &(pa[1])=%p, ", &pa, &(pa[0]), &(pa[1]));
    printf("++pa=%p\n",++pa);
    printf("*pa=%c\n",*pa);
}

int main(void)
{
    char arr[]={'c', 'a', 't'};
    char *ptr="cat";
    printf("&arr=%p, &(arr[0])=%p, &(arr[1])=%p\n", &arr, &(arr[0]), &(arr[1]));
    print(arr);
    print2(ptr);
}
```

When I compile file, I see ....

```
&arr=0x7fff1ae0d755, &(arr[0])=0x7fff1ae0d755, &(arr[1])=0x7fff1ae0d756
&ca=0x7fff1ae0d728, &ca[0]=0x7fff1ae0d755, &ca[1]=0x7fff1ae0d756, ++ca=0x7fff1ae0d756
*ca=a
&pa=0x7fff1ae0d728, &(pa[0])=0x5579970a706c, &(pa[1])=0x5579970a706d, ++pa=0x5579970a706d
*pa=a
```

Why are &ca and &pa the same? They are obviously not in the same function inside.

Comment: Parameters are, when their address is taken, passed on the "stack", the memory region for objects with "automatic storage duration" which exist only in a given scope (a block or a function). Parameters are such objects: The *parameters* visible inside a function are copies of the *arguments* the caller provides. The parameters are put on the next free address. When the function returns, the parameters "go out of scope" and the memory can be re-used, for example for a parameter of the next function.

Comment: If you call the same function from within itself (i.e., recursively, with a condition like a static counter which prevents the recursion from being infinite) you'll see that the same parameter will be on different addresses for each nested call. Parameters have no fixed address (as opposed to global and static variables); they are created ad-hoc when the need arises, i.e., when the function is called (which may be unpredictable due to user input etc.).

Comment: Thank  @Peter - Reinstate Monica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are talking about the first parameter of two functions that are called in sequence.  As the function parameters are local storage of a function, and as none of the functions is called during the call to the other, the system is free to reallocate the unused memory of one function to the other... And this is what is happening.... the same address position is used for the first parameters in the call.  This is casualty, but is quite common that the compiler uses the same arrangement for functions that have the same structure.  You will see this with high frequency, as the compiler is solving the same way the same problem.

Think that, when you call `print()`, `print2()` is not active, and *vice versa*, when you call `print2()`, `print()`, has already finished, so the compiler is free to allocate the same address for two different variables (and, in this case, it is probably the first free position in the stack)

Answer (score 0):

Peter's comment explained why the address can be the same.
The behavior could be different for different compilers.
For example, gcc and icc give different result:

```
 ./a1.gcc
&arr=0x7fffffffe1b5, &(arr[0])=0x7fffffffe1b5, &(arr[1])=0x7fffffffe1b6
&ca=0x7fffffffe198, &ca[0]=0x7fffffffe1b5, &ca[1]=0x7fffffffe1b6, ++ca=0x7fffffffe1b6
*ca=a
&pa=0x7fffffffe198, &(pa[0])=0x55555555606c, &(pa[1])=0x55555555606d, ++pa=0x55555555606d
*pa=a

❯ ./a1.icc
&arr=0x7fffffffe110, &(arr[0])=0x7fffffffe110, &(arr[1])=0x7fffffffe111
&ca=0x7fffffffe100, &ca[0]=0x7fffffffe110, &ca[1]=0x7fffffffe111, ++ca=0x7fffffffe111
*ca=a
&pa=0x7fffffffe108, &(pa[0])=0x4040a0, &(pa[1])=0x4040a1, ++pa=0x4040a1
*pa=a
❯
```

Comment: Thank for @Guoyang, I learned a lot from your example.